# Unable to install the "copy" library in Python

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install the "copy" library for Python through pip but it can't find it. I've tried the following and similar names, but nothing worked:

```
pip install copy
```

Any clue on the real name of the library? I need it to build a docker container.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a standard library module named copy, is that what you want?

Comment: `copy` is built into python, and thus requires no installation.. If you're talking about a library you found referenced on the internet somewhere - please show us that reference. Otherwise, we don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: I'm using the copy.deepcopy() function in my code, documentation can found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html. However, there is no reference about the name to be used when installed through pip.

Comment: You dont need to install it, it is already installed

Comment: That's why I couldn't it then, thanks!

Comment: Yes, to clarify, that is what @DanielMesejo and Shadow meant by "built into" the "standard library."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"copy" is a standard python library, so you don't need to install it just "import copy" in your code. If you need to use a library consider checking out built in libraries first.
You can see built in libraries in list in website: https://docs.python.org/3/library/